# CMAKE version won't change

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cmake, path

I made a change in a shell script to use a version of cmake and can't find this script. I want to use cmake-3.18.5, I have installed it and changed the path to it in bashrc, but it still uses the older version cmake-3.18.2. How to find where this happens?

Comment: So, what version is output by ``cmake --version``?

Comment: it is 3.18.2. I added in bashrc export PATH="/HOME/cmake-3.18.5/bin/cmake:$PATH" and did source ~/.bashrc. But still uses old version

Comment: Probably, you call `cmake` not from the **bash** terminal, so `.bashrc` isn't used. BTW, you may print actual value of `PATH` variable (via `echo $PATH`) and check whether your path is appended to it.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem appears to be that you put the *filename* in your path, not the *directory*.

First, try this at the command line to make sure `cmake` is installed:

```
/HOME/cmake-3.18.5/bin/cmake --version
```

Then if that works, change your path on the command line:

```
export PATH=/HOME/cmake-3.18.5/bin:$PATH
```

Note that `PATH` takes directories, not files or executables.

Now type

```
type -aP cmake
```

Make sure the right directory shows up (`/HOME/cmake-3.18.5/bin/cmake`)

Now put this path command in your `.bashrc` file and see if it works this time.